# Git cloning repository using SourceTree with Bitbucket: error Server unexpectedly closed network connection

Tags: windows, git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am cloning a repository in Windows, using SourceTree but an unexpected error appears:

```
git -c filter.lfs.smudge= -c filter.lfs.required=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks clone --branch master git@bitbucket.org:xxxxxxx/xxxxxx-repo.git C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Workspace\repos\xxxxxxx-repo
Cloning into 'C:\Users\xxxxxx\Workspace\repos\olivhere-repo'...
FATAL ERROR: Server unexpectedly closed network connection
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Comment: Found any solution?